# PE Format Headers Confusion

Tags: windows, binary, portable-executable

I was looking through an executable in PEView and I found that the RVA listed in the DataDirectory for the imports table was 0x649c and the imports table was at offset 0x649c in the file, implying that the imports table starts off at the same offset in memory as it does in disk. I checked the section headers and it seems that, despite the VirtualSize and SizeOfRawData being different for every section, the RVA and PointerToRawData are always the same. How can this be if the sizes are different?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same field - if you are looking at a file on disk it is the file offset. If the module is loaded, the loader replaces this value with the RVA in memory.

Comment: I thought the loader just added the image base to the RVA.

Comment: Can you explain how the loader "generates" this new RVA?

Comment: I don't remember the details off the top of my head. Get the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) from the msdn web site.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer has the newer 4 kb hard drive sector size so that is why the offsets were the same.